# Decorator pattern java, helper methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods, decorator, helper

Can decorator pattern access helper methods? Let's say I have a flag installed on a flagpole. The flag has two methods; wave and calculateWind where the latter is a helper. The result of the following code will be;

"this is decorated"

... seeing as the decorated helper is never called. Is there a way for the flagImpl to refer to the already instantiated caller object's calculateWind rather than its own helper? Or is there a way to go about this generally within a decorator pattern.

```
psvm(){
    flag = new decoratedFlag(new flagImpl());
    flag.wave();
}

public interface flag(){
   int wave();
   int calculateWind();
}

public class flagImpl implements flag{
   int wave(){ calculateWind(); }
   int calculateWind(){ return 8; }
}

public class decoratedFlag implements flag{
   private flag;
   
   public decoratedFlag(flag flag){
      this.flag = flag;
   }

   int wave(){ 
     sout("this is decorated");
     return flag.wave(); 
   }
   int calculateWind(){ 
     sout("this is ALSO decorated");
     return calculateWind(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: `flag.calculateWind()`

Comment: Whole point is that calculateWind is run as a helper from wave(). I'm asking if somehow this call to helper method could refer to the decorator's calculateWind()

Comment: Decorators only work when the methods are called _on the decorator_. In other words, they only work for _external_ interaction. The decorator does not change the internals of the object it is decorating.

Comment: Yeah i figured, was just wondering if there was any workaround that doesn't change the internal structure

Comment: Sorry, I misread. This might be a case where extension fits your needs better than a decorator. Another option is to split the two methods into separate interfaces such as `Flag` and `WindCalculator` and have a `WindCalculator` instance injected into `FlagImpl`.

Comment: It seems you are thinking of inheritance, where there are two classes, _but only one object_. This is why it's said that [inheritance violates encapsulation](https://wiki.c2.com/?InheritanceBreaksEncapsulation): a single object has knowledge of multiple class implementations. A Decorator (or composition in general) includes two classes, _and two separate objects_. The object being wrapped has no knowledge of its wrapper, and thus no way to invoke its wrapper's methods. So violating encapsulation is sometimes appropriate and necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to call methods `wave()` and `calculateWind` of `flagImpl` class. If it is true, then you should create a base class or abstract class and inherit it in derived, child classes.

Let me show an example via C#. I am sorry, I am not Java guy, however I've provided comments how code can be converted to Java.

This is your interface. In my view, this interface can be removed.

```
public interface IFlag
{
    int Wave();
    
    int CalculateWind();
}
```

This is an abstract class:

```
// "implements" in Java
public abstract class FlagImplementation : IFlag
{
    // @Override in Java
    public virtual int CalculateWind()
    {
        return 8;
    }

    // @Override in Java
    public virtual int Wave()
    {
        return CalculateWind();
    }
}
```

And child class looks like this. You can call here methods of base class:

```
// "extends"   in Java
public class DecoratedFlag : FlagImplementation
{
    // "@Override" in Java
    // Overriding methods defined in the abstract superclass
    public override int Wave()
    {
        // "base" should be replaced with "super" in Java
        return base.Wave() + 100;
    }

    // "@Override" in Java
    // Overriding methods defined in the abstract superclass
    public override int CalculateWind()
    {
        // "base" should be replaced with "super" in Java
        return base.CalculateWind() + 300;
    }
}
```

And you can run the above code like this:

```
DecoratedFlag decoratedFlag = new DecoratedFlag();

Console.WriteLine($"CalculateWind: {decoratedFlag.CalculateWind()}"); // OUTPUT: 
    // CalculateWind: 308
Console.WriteLine($"Wave: {decoratedFlag.Wave()}"); // OUTPUT: Wave: 408
```

[Read more about Decorator pattern with Java examples here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#C#)

Comment: It's dawned on me that I probably didn't specify my question enough. My bad! My only point was is there was any way of going about decorating helper methods at runtime w/o inheritance and only using composition. I appreciate the answer very much tho.

Comment: @RasmusHjorthLüdeking thanks for your comment. However, could you elaborate what `helper method` is in what class. I mean name of class and name of methods. And where do you want to use composition?